# Eclipse C++ formatting

Tags: c++, eclipse, formatting

Is there a way to make eclipse format stuff like this:

```
int x;
bool hasX;
MyClass longName;
```

into:

```
int     x;
bool    hasX;
MyClass longName;
```

I think I once did it in Java Eclipse, but I can't seem to find it in the eclipse c++ format options.

Edit:
I don't have such option in my formatter [image]

Comment: Press the tab key, or do you mean automatically?

Comment: While formatting (ctrl+shift+f)

Answer (score 0):

In the preference--> C++-->Code Style-->Formatter
Click the "Edit" button, in the "Indentation" tab, check the "Use spaces to indent wrapped lines". 
Once this is done, pressing "Ctrl+Shift+F" in the editor will automatically align the text the way you have asked.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I could be blind but I can't seem to find such option. see edit.

Comment: It could be because default formatting profile won't allow you or show the option "Edit" in it. So create a new one by clicking "New" under the active profile and then you will find your way into this.:)

Comment: what? I'm in a profile called Vlad.. see image please.

Comment: okay, my eclipse seems bit different in appearance. But I could still guess things here. Try checking the "use tabs only for leading indentations" under "Tab policy". I guess this will resolve your issue.

Comment: To enable this check box, you will have to change the "Spaces only" to "Tabs Only".

Comment: @Vladp: Come to [ChatRoom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22091/teenage-programmers-chatroom)